# Why is my first int value in C always 0 although I assign another value than 0?

Tags: c, integer, zero

I build a simple Calculator in C where I Put at first my first value number1, then the operation (+, -, *, /) and then the second value number2.

always when i put in the value of number1 via scanf i can see in the output console, that only my first value number1 gets the value 0.

Can you say me why this happens?

`

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(){
    int number1;
    int number2;
    char operation;
    int userResult;

    printf("Please enter the first number: ");
    scanf("%d", &number1);

    printf("\nPlease enter the operation: ");
    scanf("%s", &operation);

    printf("\nPlease enter the second number: ");
    scanf("%d", &number2);

    printf("\nPlease give me your guessed result: ");
    scanf("%d", &userResult);

    printf("---------------------------------------------------------------");

    switch (operation)
    {
    case '+':
        
        printf("\nyou are right:  %d + %d = %d", number1, number2, (number1+number2));
        break;
    
    case '-':
        
        printf("\nyou are right:  %d - %d = %d", number1, number2, (number1-number2));
        break;

    case '*':
        
        printf("\nyou are right:  %d * %d = %d", number1, number2, (number1*number2));
        break;

    case '/':
        
        printf("\nyou are right:  %d / %d = %d", number1, number2, (number1/number2));
        break;

    default:
        break;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

`

`Please enter the first number: 32

Please enter the operation: +

Please enter the second number: 66

### Please give me your guessed result: 9

you are right:  0 + 66 = 66

`

Here in the output you can see, that my number1 value is 32. but in the last line it gets the value 0.

Comment: The `scanf` format `%s` is to read ***null-terminated** strings*, not single characters. The call `scanf("%s", &operation)` with the input `'+'` will write the `'+'` to `operation`. Then it will write the string null-terminator somewhere else in memory. To read a single character use `%c`. But add a space before, to skip the newline leftover from the previous `scanf` call: `scanf(" %c", &operation)`

Comment: On another note, you should *always* check what `scanf` [***returns***](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf#Return_value). Or to better handle invalid input, use e.g. `fgets` to read a while line as a string, and then use other functions to parse the string. For example `sscanf`, but again remember to check what it returns.